# Called function instance must depend on parameter

Tags: c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae, overload-resolution

I would like to make the function call depend on the parameter, that is, what version of the function is being called. I'm looking for a way to make the following code work, without making `enum_value v` a template argument. The goal is that if `v==enum_value::A`, the first instance is called. If `v==enum_value::B` the second instance must be called.

```
enum class enum_value { A, B, C };

auto foo(enum_value v) -> std::enable_if_t<v==enum_value::A>
{}

auto foo(enum_value v) -> std::enable_if_t<v==enum_value::B>
{}
```

Feel free to ask if I need to elaborate.

Comment: I call XY-problem -- what's your use case? You can't do that directly, since overload resolution and template instantiations are compile-time processes, while your value comes up at runtime. But there's probably a solution to the actual problem you've encountered.

Comment: I was creating multiple solutions for a certain problem. I was just wondering whether this was a way too. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to make the following code work, without making enum_value v a template argument

I don't think it's possible what do you want.

As pointed by Quentin, if the enum value is a function argument, it is known (potentially) only run-time. But the compiler have to select the function compile-time.

You can think that make `foo()` `constexpr`, passing a `constexpr` value as arguments, permit a compile time selection of the right function. But this doesn't works because a `constexpr` function can be executed compile-time, but can also be executed run-time. So the compiler give error because must consider the run-time case.

The best I can imagine (non a great solution, I know) is pass through a select function; something as

```
enum class enum_value { A, B, C };

void foo_A ()
 { }

void foo_B ()
 { }

// ....

void select_foo (enum_value v)
 {
   switch (v)
    {
      case A: foo_A(); break;
      case B: foo_B(); break;
      // ...
      default: break;             
    }
 }
```